# How to fill text value as zero when there is no class found in the webpage response (scrapy)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

While practicing web scraping how to scrape a e-commerce site, I want to scrape all the 4 products information price and discount of the product page.But for one product there is class for discount and it only retrieves three values instead of four in discount response. How to fill null or zero values for discount in this case of missing class?

```
<div class="prd_p_section">
    <div class="ori_price">
        <span class="p_price">Rs.23899</span>
        <span class="prd_discount">20% Off</span>                            
     </div>
     <div class="old_prices">                                                                        
         <span>Rs 28999</span>
         <span>Rs 29999</span>                                                                                  
      </div>
      <div class="multi_tags_pl">
      </div>                          
</div>
.
.
.
.
.
.
<div class="prd_p_section">
    <div class="ori_price">
        <span class="p_price">Rs.11590</span>                            
     </div>
     <div class="old_prices">                                                                        
         "
         "                                                                                  
      </div>
      <div class="multi_tags_pl">
    </div>                          
</div>
```

my code:

```
In [47]: fetch('https://www.shopclues.com/big-battery-smartphones.html')
In [45]: response.css('.p_price::text').extract()
Out[45]: ['Rs.23899', 'Rs.23899', 'Rs.43999', 'Rs.11590']

In [46]: response.css('.prd_discount::text').extract()
Out[46]: ['20% Off', '19% Off', '27% Off']
```

expected result:

```
In [45]: response.css('.p_price::text').extract()
Out[45]: ['Rs.23899', 'Rs.23899', 'Rs.43999', 'Rs.11590']

In [46]: response.css('.prd_discount::text').extract()
Out[46]: ['20% Off', '19% Off', '27% Off', 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are three element on page, scrapy will return you three element, not four. So I suppose you to use post processing of scraped data. For example, you can try to use `itertools.izip_longest`, it lets you to combine arrays of unequal length. Here is an example:

```
import itertools

prices = ['Rs.23899', 'Rs.23899', 'Rs.43999', 'Rs.11590']
discounts = ['20% Off', '19% Off', '27% Off']
for i in itertools.izip_longest(prices, discounts):
    print i
```

This will output you:

```
('Rs.23899', '20% Off')
('Rs.23899', '19% Off')
('Rs.43999', '27% Off')
('Rs.11590', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will scrape data incorrectly if for example: page contains 4 products and 2-nd product without discount(not last one as on example).
Your result of `response.css('.prd_discount::text').extract()` doesn't indicate which exact 1 of 4 products is without discount option.
I propose to add price/discount data in each item section of page separately:

```
data = []
for item_container in response.css("div.prd_p_section"):
    price = item_container.css(".p_price::text").extract_first()
    discount = item_container.css(".prd_discount::text").extract_first()
    data.append([price,discount])
```